# Existen los bucles en mysql, duda?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Tengo está relación:

[image: posible bucle en mysql]

Como veis:

- los departamentos están relacionados con las unidades
- los departamentos están relacionado con las provincias
- las provincias están relacionada con las unidades

Quería saber si este tipo de relación está permitida en MySQL o si, por contra, generaría un bucle infinito.

Comment: Ese tipo de relación es permitida. Otra cosa es que sea correcta, como menciona @alfabravo en su respuesta, parece que hay redudancia de información puesto que la provincia ya incluye el departamento. Eso puede generar problemas pues una unidad podría pertenecer a dos departamentos distintos. También hay tablas con referencias a ellas mismas, pero no por ello se forma un bucle. Es decir, si parece un bucle, pero un modelo de base de datos no es un flujo ni se debe interpretar como tal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues, así como está, tienes una relación M-N entre Unidad y provincia. Aparte de eso, hay una relación 1-N entre Provincia y Unidad. No se trata de que haya bucles infinitos (a menos que tengas triggers funcionando sobre esas tablas) sino de que sea difícil cumplir con todas las restricciones cuando intentes insertar un registro en la tabla Unidad.

¿Has pensado en definir mejor los atributos que conservas en cada tabla? Digamos que cada Provincia tiene un id_departamento y posiblemente no necesites tener duplicado el id del departamento en cada Unidad. Con saber la provincia, ya sabrías el departamento porque su relación es 1-N (por cada Departamento hay N Provincias, pero para cada Provincia hay sólo un departamento).

Ya si una consulta necesita extraer esa info, puedes hacer un join o mantener una vista. Lo importante sería no almacenar información duplicada que se puede inferir a partir de las relaciones más simples entre tablas.